# Sql: Sorting row entries alphanumerically

Tags: sql, sorting, row, vertica

I have the following table in an vertica db:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Tid | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   1 | A     | B     | C     | D     |
|   2 | A     | E     | B     | D     |
|   3 | D     | A     | 5     | C     |
|   4 | B     | 1     | E     | A     |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

My goal is it to sort the rows in alphanumerically, all entries are strings. The result would look like that:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Tid | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   1 | A     | B     | C     | D     |
|   2 | A     | B     | D     | E     |
|   3 | 5     | A     | C     | D     |
|   4 | 1     | A     | B     | E     |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Usage: I am using sql to generate an apriori algorithm, in order to generate new candidates I would like to use a `F_k-1` join, which in my understanding needs sorting like requested above.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How many columns and how many rows in your source data?

Comment: Columns <6;
Rows > 1000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Don't have access to Vertica but this should do the job (although I can't grantee that this is the most efficient way / cleanest code for Vertica)

```
select      Tid
           ,min (case rn when 1 then item end)  as Item1
           ,min (case rn when 2 then item end)  as Item2
           ,min (case rn when 3 then item end)  as Item3
           ,min (case rn when 4 then item end)  as Item4

from       (select      Tid,item
                       ,row_number () over (partition by Tid order by item) as rn

            from       (            select Tid ,Item1 as item from t
                        union all   select Tid ,Item2         from t
                        union all   select Tid ,Item3         from t
                        union all   select Tid ,Item4         from t
                        ) t
            ) t

group by    Tid
```

---

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| tid | item1 | item2 | item3 | item4 |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1   | A     | B     | C     | D     |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2   | A     | B     | D     | E     |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 3   | 5     | A     | C     | D     |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 4   | 1     | A     | B     | E     |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: There are only 4 rows in the example. But there are probably many more in the expected use-case, which would make your solution quite impractical.

Comment: Yes that is correct, however one could generate the sql querry with python, but the big question is how efficient that querry will become if it is extremely long.

Comment: @CraigYoung -  You are both wrong guys. The hard-coded thing here is the number of columns, not the number of rows.

Comment: Oh, sorry I misread, you are right, however you might have numerous columns in a table, which would lead to generate the querry with python or similar tools.

Comment: I admit I has misread your solution, but you're still generating an intermediate result set of nxm rows. Which I assume is why you called out the caveat on efficiency.

Comment: It should do the trick, and it's a nice demonstration of 'manual' unpivot and pivot. Given volumes provided OP and (hopefully correct) napkin math this should have complexity around `O(R * C * ln(R * C))` whereas the best case performance would be: `O(R * C * ln(C))`

Comment: @valenzio I wouldn't hold out hope on doing something like this **without** hand-coding or script-generating the appropriate query on a case-by-case basis. The SQL language is designed to operate on columns. And even when you sort columns, row integrity is maintained. What you're trying to do is something SQL really isn't designed to for. I wouldn't be surprised if it turns out to be more efficient to: use python, read each row into an array, sort the array, and write back. (_Curse not being able to edit comments; missing word significantly changes meaning._)

Comment: @CraigYoung Yes I am also debating if it is worse doing that in sql or not, I need to do some benchmarks.